# icacls.exe is not working properly on Windows 10 OS

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, icacls

I am working with installer which invokes icacls.exe to set folder permissions using powershell inorder to remove the "users" permission if already allowed & provides permissions for Admin & IIS users. The script is

```
$folderPermissionList = (Get-Acl "C:\Program Files\Workspace").Access | ?{$_.IdentityReference -match "$BUILTIN\\Users"} | Select IdentityReference,FileSystemRights
If($folderPermissionList.FileSystemRights -match "FullControl")
{
   Write-Host "Inside condition"
   & icacls.exe "C:\Program Files\Workspace" /Q /T /remove "BUILTIN\Users"
}
   Write-Host "outside condition"
   & icacls.exe "C:\Program Files\Workspace" /Q /T /grant "BUILTIN\Administrators:`(OI`)`(CI`)`(F`)"
   & icacls.exe "C:\Program Files\Workspace" /Q /T /grant "BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:`(OI`)`(CI`)`(F`)"
```

The above script is working on Windows servers but it is not working in Windows 10 OS. Tried with Powershell also there is no response it is hanged in the icacls command.

[image]

Powershell version: 5.1.19041.1151
Windows 10 Enterprise [21H1]

Note: executed with elevated permission & it got stuck [refer attached results]

Any idea why it is not executing on Windows 10? or other approach to set the permissions without any issues like this?

Comment: "*...or other approach to set the permissions without any issues like this?*" The PowerShell way: use the appropriate [`cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview): [`Set-Acl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl)

Comment: Please confirm that the Builtin\Users permission you're attempting to remove is not inherited and is explicitly applied at the path you're referencing with the /remove command.

Comment: it is inherited.

Comment: Then the issue is not `icacls` or the fact you're not using `Set-ACL` its that you cannot remove an inherited permission. You could use `/inheritance:d` before `/remove`, this will Disable inheritance and copy the ACEs.

Comment: Get-ACL is very slow because the specified folder have more 55k files with sub folder... It is nearly taking 20mins to complete. Is there any other way to minimize it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same difficulty
"dir -Force" was telling "d-r---" on parent dir, "-a-hs-" on unique file in dir.
icacls was telling "done" but didn't change anything, "rm" was still refused.
get-acl was saying "Full Control"

=> I did "rm -rf" from wsl ubuntu and it worked easy :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35286536)